# Htaccess load content from folder outside root directory

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, directory, root

I have website "firstdomain.com" with webhosting. Then I have "secondomain.com" domain without hosting. I would like to load content into "seconddomain.com" from folder which is located on "firstdomain.com" webhosting. But this folder is outside root folder, where .htaccess is located. Webhosting is located in "var/www/vhosts/httpdocs/firstdomain.com/httpdocs"  and the folder with second presentation is located in "var/www/vhosts/httpdocs/firstdomain.com/seconddomain".

This piece of code is working only when both presentations are in the same root folder. It means the second presentation is in folder "var/www/vhosts/httpdocs/firstdomain.com/httpdocs/seconddomain". But I don't want have both presentation in same root folder, because of safety (hacking etc). I use Plesk virtual server with Apache. Can you show me the correct way how modify this part of code to load content outside root folder ?

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/secondomain/
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} secondomain\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /seconddomain/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Sorry, but it is unclear what your actual situation is. What do you mean by "without hosting"? Is your http server setup to answer to "seconddomain.com" at all? Is address resolution setup correctly? If not, then you can do whatever rewriting you can imagine, it won't help.

Comment: It means "firstdomain.com" is domain with hosting. "Seconddomain.com" is domain set as alias for "firstdomain.com" and loading content from "firstdomain.com" folder. Everything is working fine when this folder is located in "var/www/vhosts/httpdocs/firstdomain.com/httpdocs/seconddomain". My problem is I need locate this folder with secondomain content outside root folder.

Comment: Well, you can use an `Alias` directive to publish any folder you want under some path and then use a rewriting rule to redirect requests to that second host name to that virtual path (the folder has been published under). That is _not_ possible by using dynamic configuration files though (`.htaccess`) for obvious reasons, but only in the real http servers host configuration.

Answer (score 0):

You can use full paths in rules:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} seconddomain\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /var/www/vhosts/httpdocs/firstdomain.com/seconddomain/$1 [L]
```

But you would also need to grant permissions for Apache to access a folder outside document root, in a `Directory` block. It's not the usual way to do this. Can't you just set up another `VirtualHost`?